# How to check whether the Input Text Field is visible or hidden in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an input text field which has

```
style: "visibility: visible"
```

or

```
style: "visibility: hidden"
```

What is the easiest way to find out if it is visible or not ?

Suppose the input text field is E. What should be the condition here:

```
if <something with E> {
    alert("The text filed is visible !!");
}
```

?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
if(element.style.visibility == "visible") {
    alert("The text filed is visible !!");
}
```

If you also need code to get the element, here's an example by the id attribute:

```
var element = document.getElementById("myInputID");
if(element.style.visibility == "visible") {
    alert("The text filed is visible !!");
}
```

The above code would find an element like this (note IDs should be unique):

```
<input type="text" id="myInputID" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(document.getElementByid(YOUR_OBJECT_ID_HERE).style.visbility == 'hidden')
{
   alert('Hidden');
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
is(":visible");
```

something like

```
$(this).is(":visible"); //here $(this) is your element
```